# Disable NSWindow Interaction

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I am attempting to develop a custom `NSAlert` using `NSWindow`. When the custom alert `NSWindow` is triggered from the main application window, the user is still able to interact with the main window and access the menu bar whilst the alert window is still active. I believe when a `NSAlert` is presented, such actions are disabled and a 'Funk' sound is played upon any attempt to interact with the main window.

How would I disable interaction with the main window (and possibly play a 'Funk' sound) until the user has acted on the alert window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your custom window as a "modal" window. The simplest way is to use the `runModal(for:)` method of `NSApplication`. Actions which should complete or dismiss the modal dialog should call `stopModal()` or `stopModal(withCode:)`.